# Cannot resolve conflict on Git (remote is 1 commit ahead)

Tags: git, git-pull, merge-conflict-resolution, git-extensions

A project that I'm working on has around 200 submodules. I made some modifications in my local repo, around changes to 150 submodules without commit & pushing.

But it turns out that just when I was about to commit & push, I noticed that another teammate had made recently a push in the remote repo. Son now, the remote repo is one commit ahead from my local.

My attempted solutions:

1. Whenever I try to push my changes, it says that it can't be possible because the remote repo is ahead.
   So I tried to force push my changes (my teammate and I agreed that I can do this), but the branch is protected by an administrator. I can't be done.
2. Since that didn't worked, I tried to simply Pull the latest changes and updating recursively the submodules (submodule update --init -recursive). I'm getting the following error:

`error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout`

In Git Extensions output error window:

[image]

What would you do to solve this issue?

Comment: “Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.” I.e. the answer by Jim.

Answer (score 2):

`git stash` was made for this: it sets uncommitted changes aside until you're ready for them. You can use either `git stash pop` or `git stash apply` to put those changes back into your working directory after you've resolved your conflicts. (`pop` removes the stash from the list; `apply` does not.)

There's more documentation available at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash.